# Grey line on page, border top/bottom somewhere that I can't seem to find

Tags: html, css, web

working on a site at the minute and have a part really annoying me, there seems to be a fixed position element with a border top/bottom set on it that results in a horizontal grey line on the page.
I've tried finding it with inspect element etc but am having trouble identifying it, can anyone help out?

Example [here.](http://www.marcmurray.net/sbls/index.html)

EDIT: Url

Comment: If you can't find the matching styles then maybe it's a `hr` element.

Comment: yes it's hr element...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its an `<hr>` element just after `div#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1`

Answer (score 0):

There is a `<hr>` tag right after the closing of this tag 
`<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">`
the comment above the div is "Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling". Delete that, grey line goes away. That is if that's the grey line you're talking about :)